# How to scale a UIImage to fit screen based on height and width of device

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, image-scaling

I have a `UIScrollView` and inside it i have a `UIImage` which i get from my server. Each image will either have its `width` greater than the `height` or the `height` greater than its `width`.

I would like to scale the image in such a way that it fits my device screen perfect based on the `height` or `width`

**For example:** 
I get the image from server and check which is greater, the `width` or the `height`.

```
if let width = image?.size.width, let height = image?.size.height {
    if width > height {
        print("Width is greater than height")
    }else              
        print("Height is greater than width")
    }                
}
```

Once i do this i would like to scale the image in one of these 2 ways.

**Option 1:** 
If the `width` is greater than the `height` then i would like the image to be scaled with respect to its `height` being fixed to device height and width should be `scrollable` in the view.

**Option 2:**
If the `height` is greater than the `width` then i would like the image to be scaled with respect to its `width` being fixed to device width and height should be `scrollable` in the view.

I have managed to get `Option 2` to work with this function.

```
func scaleImageWidth(sourceImage:UIImage, scaledToWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width
    let scaleFactor = scaledToWidth / oldWidth

    let newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
    sourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:newWidth, height:newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

I have modified the function to work for `Option 1` like so:

```
func scaleImageHeight(sourceImage: UIImage, scaledToHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let oldheight: CGFloat = sourceImage.size.height
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = scaledToHeight / oldheight

    let newWidth: CGFloat = sourceImage.size.width * scaleFactor
    let newHeight: CGFloat = oldheight * scaleFactor
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    sourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Now both these functions work fine, but in both cases there are some situations where the scaling causes the image to scale smaller than the `width` or `height` of the device.

Here are some images of how it looks when the scaling goes wrong.

**Actual Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image: GIF Image of Expected Result]

**EDITED:**

Here are a few images for whose `height` and `width` these functions work properly.

**Case 1:** When Height is greater than width

1. Width: 1080.0, Height: 2280.0
2. Width: 1080.0, Height: 2160.0
3. Width: 1083.0, Height: 1920.0
4. Width: 1080.0, Height: 2160.0

**Case 2:** When Width is greater than height

1. Width: 2715.0, Height: 1920.0
2. Width: 1945.0, Height: 1920.0
3. Width: 2278.0, Height: 1920.0

Here are a few images for whose `height` and `width` these function produces the above mentioned problem.

**Case 1:** When Height is greater than width

1. Width: 1300.0, Height: 1920.0
2. Width: 1143.0, Height: 1920.0
3. Width: 1281.0, Height: 1920.0

**Case 2:** When Width is greater than height

I have not noticed any issues for when width is greater than height. It always produces the right results in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trying. I solved this problem after i read `@DonMag` answer. Where its mentioned that the issue could be due to not considering the `aspect ratio` of the image.

In my scenario I had to have a `UIScrollView` and have the image fill the scrollView according its `width` & `height`.  And it had to scroll only in one direction either `Vertically` or `Horizontally` based on the aspect ratio of the image.

To achieve this i used only 1 function from the question above which is `OPTION 1` and i modified it as below.

```
func scaleImageHeight(sourceImage: UIImage, scaledToHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let oldheight: CGFloat = sourceImage.size.height
    let scaleFactor: CGFloat = scaledToHeight / oldheight

    let newWidth: CGFloat = sourceImage.size.width * scaleFactor
    let newHeight: CGFloat = oldheight * scaleFactor
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    sourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

    //This check is added as the scaling function would scale down an image to a size which was less than the width of the screen. 
    if newWidth < self.view.frame.width{
        let differenceWidth = self.view.frame.width - newWidth
        newWidth = self.view.frame.width
        newHeight = newHeight+differenceWidth
    }

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

So the solution that worked for me, to match the clients requirement was to scale the image always by the `height` of the image regardless of whether the `height` or `width` is greater than the other.

And after scaling if the width of scaled image was less than screen width then I scale the image back up to the `width` so that it fits on the screen without any blank spaces. This scaling would result in the `height` to be scrollable.

**Note:**

1. `ImageView` should have a `contentMode` of `aspectFill`.
2. This solution may not work for everyone as the images used for scaling here are custom designed images.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be that you are comparing the image's width : height, but you are not taking into consideration the aspect-ratio of the imageView.

Here is a `CGSize` extension to calculate either the `aspectFit` or `aspectFill` size, based on a "source" size (the image size) and a "target" size (the imageView size).

```
extension CGSize {
    func aspectFit(sourceSize: CGSize, targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let vWidth = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
        let vHeight = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;
        var returnSize = targetSize
        if( vHeight < vWidth ) {
            returnSize.width = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height * sourceSize.width;
        }
        else if( vWidth < vHeight ) {
            returnSize.height = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width * sourceSize.height;
        }
        return returnSize;
    }
    func aspectFill(sourceSize: CGSize, targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let vWidth = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
        let vHeight = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;
        var returnSize = targetSize
        if( vHeight > vWidth ) {
            returnSize.width = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height * sourceSize.width;
        }
        else if( vWidth > vHeight ) {
            returnSize.height = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width * sourceSize.height;
        }
        return returnSize;
    }
}
```

For your case, you want to get the `aspectFill` size.

Here is a simple, full example that compares the output of your original calculations to the `aspectFill` calculation. I used the image sizes you added to your question, and an imageView size of `375 x 667` (full-screen on an iPhone 7):

```
extension CGSize {
    func aspectFit(sourceSize: CGSize, targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let vWidth = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
        let vHeight = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;
        var returnSize = targetSize
        if( vHeight < vWidth ) {
            returnSize.width = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height * sourceSize.width;
        }
        else if( vWidth < vHeight ) {
            returnSize.height = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width * sourceSize.height;
        }
        return returnSize;
    }
    func aspectFill(sourceSize: CGSize, targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let vWidth = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
        let vHeight = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;
        var returnSize = targetSize
        if( vHeight > vWidth ) {
            returnSize.width = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height * sourceSize.width;
        }
        else if( vWidth > vHeight ) {
            returnSize.height = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width * sourceSize.height;
        }
        return returnSize;
    }
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    let testSizes: [CGSize] = [

        // width > height
        CGSize(width: 2715.0, height: 1920.0),
        CGSize(width: 1945.0, height: 1920.0),
        CGSize(width: 2278.0, height: 1920.0),

        // used to provide a blank line in debug output
        CGSize.zero,

        // height > width
        CGSize(width: 1080.0, height: 2280.0),
        CGSize(width: 1080.0, height: 2160.0),
        CGSize(width: 1083.0, height: 1920.0),
        CGSize(width: 1080.0, height: 2160.0),

        // used to provide a blank line in debug output
        CGSize.zero,

        // height > width problems
        CGSize(width: 1300.0, height: 1920.0),
        CGSize(width: 1143.0, height: 1920.0),
        CGSize(width: 1281.0, height: 1920.0),

    ]

    let imageViewSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print()

        testSizes.forEach { sz in
            if sz == CGSize.zero {
                print()
            } else {
                // original size calcs
                if sz.height > sz.width {
                    let newSZ = scaleImageWidth(sourceImageSize: sz, scaledToWidth: imageViewSize.width)
                    print("Orig: \(newSZ)")
                } else {
                    let newSZ = scaleImageHeight(sourceImageSize: sz, scaledToHeight: imageViewSize.height)
                    print("Orig: \(newSZ)")
                }
                // aspectFill calc
                let newSZ = sz.aspectFill(sourceSize: sz, targetSize: imageViewSize)
                print("Fill: \(newSZ)")
            }
        }

        print()

    }

    func scaleImageWidth(sourceImageSize: CGSize, scaledToWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let oldWidth = sourceImageSize.width
        let scaleFactor = scaledToWidth / oldWidth

        let newHeight = sourceImageSize.height * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor

        return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    }

    func scaleImageHeight(sourceImageSize: CGSize, scaledToHeight: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let oldheight: CGFloat = sourceImageSize.height
        let scaleFactor: CGFloat = scaledToHeight / oldheight

        let newWidth: CGFloat = sourceImageSize.width * scaleFactor
        let newHeight: CGFloat = oldheight * scaleFactor

        return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    }

}
```

This is what you should get in the debug console:

```
Orig: (943.1796875, 667.0)
Fill: (943.1796875, 667.0)
Orig: (675.6848958333334, 667.0)
Fill: (675.6848958333334, 667.0)
Orig: (791.3677083333333, 667.0)
Fill: (791.3677083333333, 667.0)

Orig: (375.0, 791.6666666666666)
Fill: (375.0, 791.6666666666666)
Orig: (375.0, 750.0)
Fill: (375.0, 750.0)
Orig: (375.0, 664.819944598338)
Fill: (376.2296875, 667.0)
Orig: (375.0, 750.0)
Fill: (375.0, 750.0)

Orig: (374.99999999999994, 553.8461538461538)
Fill: (451.61458333333337, 667.0)
Orig: (375.0, 629.9212598425197)
Fill: (397.0734375, 667.0)
Orig: (375.0, 562.0608899297424)
Fill: (445.0140625, 667.0)
```

As you can see, the "problematic" sizes you posted get distinctly different return sizes.

Comment: Hey i tried your solution and for sure it pointed me in the right direction. But the result was not exactly what we were looking for. Your solution worked but behaved differently for different images when embedded in a scrollview. So ultimately we were able get the exact result by modifying the scaling function I posted in the question according to their requirement to get the desired output. I will compile an answer of the same and post it. But your answer helped so I am Upvoting it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIImageView constraints to top,left,right,bottom.
Now go to Attributes Inspector of UIIMageView and set Content Mode property to Scale To Fill.

In this case some images may be stretched.

Comment: My `constraints` and `Content mode` is fine. It has something to do with my scaling `function`. I need to either add a check to make sure the image does not scale lower than the size of the device screen or i need to re-write the whole scaling function in a different way. Coz i would say for 90% of the images it works fine. Its just some cases when the scaling causes the image to scale either the `width` or `height` to a value which is lower than the screen's `width` or `height`

Comment: Can you attach those images? Share the link, i'll download those images and try out some code on it.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot as the client does not permit me to do so until the app is released. But i can give you the resolution of the images ... I will update my question with those details.